# Detecting city within search string

Tags: php, mysql, search

I'm currently playing around with a search algorithm for a small website I'm working on. My problem right now is, that it isn't flexible enough. My employer wants the search to be more flexible in a way it can search within cities as well.

Right now I have most of the search working, however I'm stuck with this city thing. What I want to do is to find a city name within the search string, get the city ID from the database and if the detected string actually is a city, the city name has to be removed from the original search string to do the specific search in titles and so on afterwards.

Eg. if I have the following search string "chiropractor copenhagen c" then I want to be able to find the "copenhagen c" part, get the city ID for this city and then exclude it from the rest of my search so that the rest only will search for "chiropractor".

I hope you understand what I am looking for.

Thanks

Comment: This is a hard problem, interested to see what comes up. Can you go beyond PHP/mySQL for this? i.e. install new software on your server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, due the fact, that there could be everything in the search string, you would need a list of cities in your database, and find those in the search string itself. If there is nothing similar, it would mean, even if it would be a real city, it would not be in the database, and so it would not be getable there. But if you can find a similar one, you can remove it from the search string and get the details for the city from the database.

Comment: as he wants to get the city-id from the db, he obv. has a list of cities. As he wants the id, i guess the city doesnt really matter if it is not in the database.

Comment: Exactly what I meant. If the city cannot be found in the list of cities, it can stay in the searchstring.

Comment: I got it working by first comparing the individual words of my search string to the city-database. The one with the best match in the database is then kept for city-searching and the string from which it was found is removed from the original search string. I can now search like I used to and then add the city-check to my final search string. Works like a charm.

Comment: Remember, probably the city database is really huge and if your search string has a lot of words, you search the database several times, which takes time and performance. Try to cache the cities and their IDs and build an own string comparing function for the SQL-LIKE. So you dont have to overuse the database

Answer (score 0):

As you dont know the Names of the Cities in the first place, i would suggest reading all citynames and ids from the db into an array. Then loop throught the array and look for the cityname in the search string. If you find it, you have the name and id and can add it into your query and you have the name of the city and so you can simply replace it to "" in the search string.